# Pi 3 USB USB Microphone; accessing programmtically in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, usb, raspberry-pi3, audio-processing

I am doing a speech processing project with a Raspberry Pi 3 (running Raspbian) using a USB Microphone. I can see the Microphone show up as a selectable audio device for the Pi and it produces/captures sound perfectly.

I cannot figure out how to use this in my code; I have done a ton of research regarding this and have found some tutorials but nothing that making sense. I come from more of a hardware background and have done something like this with controllers where I hook up an actual Mic and process the Analog Signal into Digital on IO Pins; I am so frustrated with this that I am about to pump data over from an Arduino using a Mic and A2D conversion.

-------------------------------------------------------My questions----------------------------------------------------
1) I want to know how to access a USB data stream or USB device in C or C++. My Linux abilities are not the best. Do I open a Serial Connection or open a filestream in "/dev/USB/...."? Can you provide a code example?

2) Regardless of the fidelity of the USB Mic Input, I want to know how to access its Input in C/C++. I have been looking at ALSA but cannot really understand a lot of its complexity. Is there something that gives me access to a raw input signal on the USB Port that I can process ( where I extrapolate out frequency, amplitude, etc.)?

I have already gone through a lot of the similar posts on here. I am really stuck on this one. I 'm really looking to understand what is going on from the OS perspective; I'll use a library given but I want to understand how it works.

Thanks!

Comment: "C/C++" is not a language.

Comment: You want to use ALSA, or OpenSLES.  Take a look at arecord.c to see how ALSA works

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, search the internet for "c++ boost asio".

Comment: I personally think python would be a better choice for this project.
Also learning to program is not an overnight thing. patience is the key. good luck.

Answer (score 2):

So an update:

So I did all of my code in C with some .sh scripts. I went ahead and figured out how to use the Alsa asoundlib (asound.h specifically). As of now, I am able to generate and record sound via USB Mic/Headset with my Pi 3. Doing so is rather arduous but here is a useful link (1).

For my project, I also found a CMU tutorial/repos for their PocketSphinx Audio Recognition Device at link (2) and video link (3). This project utilizes the Alsa asoundlib as well and was a great help for me. It takes a while to download and you need to crawl through its .sh scripts to figure out its gcc linking. But I am able to now give audio cues which are interpreted by my Pi 3 and pushed to speaker output and GPIO pins.

`LINKS`(1)http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/_2test_2pcm_8c-example.html 
(2)https://wolfpaulus.com/embedded/raspberrypi2-sr/ 
(3)https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5kp5qpwVh_8